# Potential difference between inside and outside Faraday cage

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I understand that a Faraday cage will isolate the inside from external electric fields, but I was wondering what the potential difference between the inside and outside would be in this hypothetical example.

Given the following setup, what would the potential difference between plate P1 and P2 be?

[image: faraday cage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earthed metal box and metal plate would distort the Earth's electric field as shown in this diagram taken from [Feynman - Electricity in the Atmosphere](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html).
(Note the direction of the Earth's electric field.)

[image]

What you can say for certain is that the potential of metal plate (P1) and the metal be box will be the same as that of the Earth.

*Given the following setup, what would the potential difference between plate P1 and P2 be?*

The potential distribution inside the box depends as to whether plate (P2) is charged or not.  If plate (P2) is uncharged then the answer to your question is *zero*.